# how to check if an HTML element is fully visible in browser

Tags: html

I am using DataTable and someone have to much columns.
On a page there is the possibility of applying the zoom to the body element to view the entire table as in this case.

Here an example without zoom
[image: Datatable without body zoom]

And here with zoom
[image: Here example with body zoom]

I know datatable has the option to add a horizontal scrollbar by default for cases like this but my question it's this one:

How do I understand if the table is fully displayed without knowing what the zoom of the body is?

Comment: I think you forgot the part after "mine is as follows".

Comment: Have you tried to put a width on the table `width: 100vw` and and `overflow` ?

Comment: @ScottHunter I corrected the text, thanks

Comment: @Johan Do you intend to add the overflow to be able to scroll the table horizontally?

Comment: @DmytroV yes, `overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: @Johan Thanks for the suggestion but it's not what I need. I need to know when the table is too big and overflows its container

Comment: @DmytroV the only solution I see is to set the overflow when the table is bigger than a certain point with max-width. Good luck !